# Remove focus from the textfield

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, ios6, ios7

I am doing two operations on a textfield:
1) To move the textfield using pan gesture.
2) To write on the textfield when the user clicks on it.
Concern is that I want to perform one operation at a time i.e when the user is writing he cannot scroll and vice versa.

Name of UIButton action --- button
Name of UIButton outlet --- optionButton

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    if([_optionButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"SCROLL"])
    {
        NSLog(@"can scroll");
        NSLog(@"POINT=============%d   ",point);
        point=0;
        [_optionButton setTitle:@"WRITE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        textField1.enabled=NO;
    }
    else
    {        NSLog(@"can write");
        NSLog(@"POINT=============%d   ",point);
        point=1;
        [_optionButton setTitle:@"SCROLL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        textField1.enabled=YES;
    }
}
```

The point variable is controlling the complete operation and is set to 1 at the beginning.This means that the user can write in the beginning and if he want to write he has to press the button.
The problem that I am facing is that by using "**textField1.enabled=NO**" I am not able to scroll the textfield.
Is there any function using which I can remove the focus from the textfield but can scroll it.

Comment: [textfield resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 14):

You can use this code to remove focus (As said in one of the comment),

```
[textField1 resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also remove focus from text field by calling `[textField1 endEditing:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

An UITextfield only has 1 line, so you can´t scroll it.

UPDATE

If you want to move your UITextfield with your finger use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in your parent view and apply the changes in your uitextfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow the steps:

**Implement UITextFieldDelegate into your Controller**

```
class ClassName: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {....}
```

**Implement the "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" function**

```
class ClassName: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
   }

 }
```

So returning false in textFieldShouldBeginEditing will simply not allow to edit into the UITextField.